# there is node.js scaffolding to create new project? like in visual studio for c# projects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, redux

I want to create node.js project with typescript and with express and withing the project embed the SPA client with react and redux template with typescript too. can I use some kind of scaffolding for that? to bypass all the manual labor like in visual studio for c# projects for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I was after! not exactly scaffolding tool but a great repo that has the type of project I want: https://github.com/ad548/create-react-app-express-typescript